# PHP Upgrade to 5.3.8 on Network Solutions causing 404: Page not found

Tags: php, upgrade

I have a basic php script for a contact form on a Network Solutions hosting account that used to work fine until NS upgraded PHP from 5.2.7 to 5.3.8.  The only message I get is a 404: Page not found.  When I called NS they said it was my script.  But the script is "Not Found".  What am I missing?   I would appreciate any help.

I don't have access to any error logs but here is the script, maybe you can take a look.  Thank you so much.  The other thing to note is that the OIS-MailingList.txt file is still getting written to even though when you click on the submit button it say "404: Page not found"

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name="description" content="Orion Inspection Services provides the oil and gas industry with the most highly skilled and professional workforce available." />
<title>Orion Inspection Services | Contact Us</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
   if ((strlen($_POST['name']) < 3) || (strlen($_POST['your-phone']) < 5) || (strlen($_POST['your-email']) < 5) || (strlen($_POST['c-message']) < 5))
    {
      header('Location:http://orioninspection.com/Test/message-error.html');
    }
    else
     {
      $today = date('m-d-Y');
      $filename = 'OIS-MailingList.txt';
      $file = fopen($filename,'a+b');
        echo fwrite($file,$today);
        echo fwrite($file,',');
        echo fwrite($file,$_POST['name']);
        echo fwrite($file,',');
        echo fwrite($file,$_POST['your-email']);
        echo fwrite($file,',');
        echo fwrite($file,$_POST['your-phone']);
        echo fwrite($file,"\r\n");
        header('Location:http://orioninspection.com/Test/message-success.html');

        $headers = 'From: Orion Inspection Services <info@orioninspection.com>' . "\n"; 
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; 
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

        $message .= '<b>OIS Customer Message</b><br /><br />';
        $message .= '<b>Name:</b> ' . $_POST['name'] . '<br /><br />';
        $message .= '<b>Email:</b> ' . $_POST['your-email'] . '<br /><br />';
        $message .= '<b>Phone:</b> ' . $_POST['your-phone'] . '<br /><br />';
        $message .= '<b>Message:</b> ' . $_POST['c-message'] . '<br /><br />';
        $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
        mail('info@orioninspection.com', 'OIS Customer Message', $message, $headers);
      fclose($file); 
      }
?>

</body>

</html>
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: The urls work when you remove `Test/` from the path: `http://orioninspection.com/message-success.html`

Comment: Might be worth replacing `http://orioninspection.com/Test` with a defined value, say `BASE_URL`, which is set up in a config file. You can then change this on a site-wide basis where you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Change your redirect headers to point to correct places:

```
header('Location:http://orioninspection.com/message-error.html');
...
header('Location:http://orioninspection.com/message-success.html');
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that.  Well at least I know it wasn't the upgrade

Comment: You're welcome ;) -- this kind of thing happens to all of us.